# Arrays to hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have two arrays:

```
a=["joe","mark","mark","wilson","joe"]
b=[1,2,2,3,4]
```

I need a hash:

```
h={"joe"=>[1,4],"mark"=>[2,2],"wilson"=>[3]}
```

The main problem is the keys repeat and can have multiple values. I have tried `zip`, `inject`, and `map` but I'm not able to come even remotely close to what I need. I need to use Ruby.

Comment: On what basis is 'joe' assigned 1,4, mark 2, 2 etc?

Comment: @daremkd  That is a dataset I have-I wasnt involved in the creation of the data unfortunately.But how would that be relevant to the problem here?

Comment: how do you construct the hash without knowing how the two arrays are related. On what basis would you construct the values for the key "joe"?

Comment: @Vimisha The keys are already pre defined.Both the arrays correspond to each other index by index.

Comment: If keys repeat then using a hash is not viable since the new key is just going to replace the old key.

Comment: @daremkd  Ok -I just realized that.Does anyone have a suggestion on a suitable data structure?

Comment: What you're trying to do is very common, and a hash of arrays is a valid structure when aggregating multiple values for unique keys.

Comment: @ashwinshanker see my answer if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
a=["joe","mark","mark","wilson","joe"]
b=[1,2,2,3,4]

a.zip(b).group_by{ |i,j| i }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }.to_h 
# => {"joe"=>[1, 4], "mark"=>[2, 2], "wilson"=>[3]}
```

If you're not on Ruby 2.1+, you won't have `Array#to_h` so, instead, you can do:

```
Hash[a.zip(b).group_by{ |i,j| i }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }] 
# => {"joe"=>[1, 4], "mark"=>[2, 2], "wilson"=>[3]}
```

Here's what it's doing in some intermediate steps:

```
a.zip(b) # => [["joe", 1], ["mark", 2], ["mark", 2], ["wilson", 3], ["joe", 4]]
a.zip(b).group_by{ |i,j| i } # => {"joe"=>[["joe", 1], ["joe", 4]], "mark"=>[["mark", 2], ["mark", 2]], "wilson"=>[["wilson", 3]]}
a.zip(b).group_by{ |i,j| i }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] } # => [["joe", [1, 4]], ["mark", [2, 2]], ["wilson", [3]]]
```

The star of the show here is [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), which collects all elements that match a given criteria, in this case, all array elements matching a given name. Once those are grouped, then it's just a case of cleaning up the resulting array and converting it to a Hash.

Comment: :Thank you!very clear answer-Im just learning Ruby-Looks like it was an easy solution after all

Comment: It's pretty easy once you understand the pattern. Ruby's Enumerable class has a number of very powerful methods that are useful for reorganizing and modifying arrays and hashes, and anything else that implements an enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  Here are two.

**#1**

```
a = ["joe","mark","mark","wilson","joe"]
b = [1,2,2,3,4]

Hash[a.zip(b)
      .group_by(&:first)
      .values
      .map { |arr| [arr.first.first, arr.map(&:last)] }]
  #=> { "joe"=>[1, 4], "mark"=>[2, 2], "wilson"=>[3] }
```

With Ruby 2.1:

```
a.zip(b)
 .group_by(&:first)
 .values
 .map { |arr| [arr.first.first, arr.map(&:last)] }
 .to_h
```

**#2**

```
a.zip(b)
 .each_with_object({}) { |(name,val),h| 
   h.update({name=>[val]}) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } }
  => {"joe"=>[1, 4], "mark"=>[2, 2], "wilson"=>[3]}
```

This second approach uses the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that takes a block.

Comment: Im looking to store the corresponding values as an array(not as a sum)..I think I could this modify your solution though

Comment: Thanks, it was a minor fix.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to achieve is have multiple values for a (same) key then storing the value as a double array and a bit of modification might work:

```
class Hash
  def add_key_value(key, value)
    if self.has_key?(key)
      self[key] << value
    else
      self[key] = [value]
    end
  end
end

h = Hash.new()
h.add_key_value('joe', [1,2])
p h #=> {"joe"=>[[1, 2]]}
h.add_key_value('joe', [3])
p h #=> {"joe"=>[[1, 2], [3]]}
h.add_key_value('mark', [4,5])
p h #=> {"joe"=>[[1, 2], [3]], "mark"=>[[4, 5]]}
h.add_key_value('mark', [1,2])
p h #=> {"joe"=>[[1, 2], [3]], "mark"=>[[4, 5], [1, 2]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 variants, the fastest and the shortest:

```
def fastest(a, b)
  result = {}
  i = 0

  a.each do |elem|
    result[elem] ? result[elem] << b[i] : result[elem] = [b[i]]
    i += 1
  end

  result
end

def shortest(a, b)
  a.zip(b).group_by{ |i,j| i }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }.to_h
end
```

And the benchmark results are:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  %w(fastest shortest).each do |method|
    x.report(method) { send method, ["joe","mark","mark","wilson","joe"], [1,2,2,3,4] }
  end
end

fastest   185435.9 (±19.9%) i/s -     892388 in   5.017412s
shortest   93222.0 (±20.1%) i/s -     445398 in   5.011817s
```

Comment: As a variant of `fastest`, consider: `a.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(name,i),h| (h[name] ||= []) << b[i] }`.

Answer (score 0):

The question's been answered well, but here's my code golfing attempt :)

```
a=["joe","mark","mark","wilson","joe"]
b=[1,2,2,3,4]

a.zip(b).reduce({}) {|o,(k,v)| (o[k] ||= []) << v; o}
```

The general idea is pretty close to the Tin Man's, but rather than several intermediate steps, it just takes the zipped arrays and reduces them into the target form directly.